# Curl(C++) error: can't upload file

Tags: php, c++, curl

Look to this function:

```
string PostFile(string link, string filename, string postfilename){
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    string readBuffer;

    struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
    struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
    static const char buf[] = "Expect :";

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, postfilename.c_str(),
               CURLFORM_FILE, filename.c_str(),
               CURLFORM_END);

    curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "filename",
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, filename.c_str(),
               CURLFORM_END);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);

    if(!curl) return "Error";

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, link.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);     
    curl_formfree(formpost);
    curl_slist_free_all (headerlist);

    return readBuffer;

}
```

After using

```
PostFile("http://ilovedyourmother.ga/data/test/upload.php", "LOL.txt", "uploadfile");
```

it returns error like this

```
curl_easy_perform() failed: Failed to open/read local data from file/application
```

This function based on curl postit2.c example (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html) and actually I do not quite understand how does it works. Please, find mistake in this code or at least explain what does it all does.

Comment: How did you verify that `"LOL.txt"` is where it is supposed to be?

Comment: It's in same directory with .exe file. Where must it be?

Comment: How do you execute your program?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Specifying absolute path for CURLFORM_FILE and adding CURLFORM_FILENAME options after that and giving only the file name for that option worked for me like shown below.

```
curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "image_data",
             CURLFORM_FILE, "/home/user/TestImages/123.jpg",
             CURLFORM_FILENAME, "123.jpg",
             CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "image/jpeg",
             CURLFORM_END);
```